# React - Json Schema Form dropdowns won't load initally unless I use SetTimeout function

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, dom, render, setstate

This has been driving me and my team crazy.  Here is the relevant code.

In the component's CDM we have:

```
    componentDidMount() {
    this.getContextID();
    this.getConsumerID();
    this.getEnvType();

    //setTimeout(() => this.setState({ populatedMultiSchema: this.multiSchema }), 200);
    //setTimeout(() => this.setState({ populatedMultiUISchema: this.multiUISchema }), 200);

     this.setState({ populatedMultiSchema: this.multiSchema });
     this.setState({ populatedMultiUISchema: this.multiUISchema });

}
```

so any one of the 3 methods listed will fetch the data for the dropdown.  Here is an example of one (they are all basically the same).

```
getContextID() {
    contextIDOptions = [];
    console.log("CONVERT_TARGET::", this.props.fetchTarget)
    return (
        fetch(this.props.fetchTarget + "Configuration/ContextIDs", {
            method: 'GET',
            //mode: 'cors',
            credentials: 'include',
        }).then(response => {
            if (response.status >= 400) {
                this.setState({
                    value: 'no response - status > 400'
                });
                throw new Error('no response - throw');
            }
            return response.json()
        }).then(function (json) {
            for (var contextID = 0; contextID < json.List.length; contextID++) {
                contextIDOptions.push(json.List[contextID]);
            }
            this.setState({ contextIDArray: contextIDOptions });

            console.log("got contextIDs");
        }.bind(this)).catch(() => {
            this.setState({
                value: 'no response - cb catch'
            })
        })
    )
}
```

So we set the state there to 'contextIDArray'.

Then the JSON Schema form through it's multiUISchema Object has references to these widgets that help set the values for the form.

```
ContextIDWidget = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Select one..." className="form-control" list="contextIDSelect" onChange={(event) => props.onChange(event.target.value)} />
            <datalist id="contextIDSelect">
                {this.state.contextIDArray.map((value, index) => { return <option key={index} value={value}>{value}</option> })}
            </datalist>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is the multiUISchema object (the part that matters for this discussion)

```
multiUISchema = {
    file: {
        'ui:widget': this.MultiFileWidget,
        classNames: "uiSchema"
    },

    contextID: {
        'ui:widget': this.ContextIDWidget,
        classNames: "uiSchema"
    },

}
```

And finally here it is in the return in the component.

```
        return (
        <div className="container" >
            <Form
                schema={this.state.populatedMultiSchema}
                uiSchema={this.state.populatedMultiUISchema}
                formData={this.state.formData}
                onChange={({ formData }) => { this.setState({ formData }); this.setState({ totalFileSize: this.getMultiFileSize() }); this.checkConversionSupport() }}
                onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
            >
```

So long story short, if Im using state object in the form, and Im doing setState on the objects Im using. Why do I always get a blank dropdown when I first load the component.  Shouldn't the DOM (the dropdown in this case) get repainted with the updated data from the fetches when the state object is changed?  I have console logs that show the fetched data in my inspection window so I know the data has been fetched.   This is tab component.  If I leave the tab or navigate to another page in my SPA and then go back to this page, then the dropdowns are all fully loaded.  But I can never get it just load initially unless I set these timeouts in CDM instead of just setting state.

```
   setTimeout(() => this.setState({ populatedMultiSchema: this.multiSchema }), 200);
      setTimeout(() => this.setState({ populatedMultiUISchema: this.multiUISchema }), 200);
```

I know the post is long but felt I needed  to include all the parts to get help with this. I can assure you we have been trying to resolve the issue for over a week.  We welcome any comments.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not fully familiar to your codebase. But it looks like something related about asynchronous requests. Here:

```
this.setState({ populatedMultiSchema: this.multiSchema });
this.setState({ populatedMultiUISchema: this.multiUISchema });
```

These two lines will be executed BEFORE these ones:

```
this.getContextID();
this.getConsumerID();
this.getEnvType();
```

But you expect them to get executed in reverse order. No. Your `getContextID` method making a request to a server. Javascript is asynchronous. But, by using `await` expression in an `asynchronous` function, you can pause the execution and wait for the `Promise`.

So, just update your `componentDidMount` method as below:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    await this.getContextID();
    await this.getConsumerID();
    await this.getEnvType();

    this.setState({ populatedMultiSchema: this.multiSchema });
    this.setState({ populatedMultiUISchema: this.multiUISchema });

}
```

[Here i created a Codepen](https://codepen.io/aoguzhan/pen/MvLWbG?editors=1010) on usage of `async/await`. There are some details in comments. You can play with it as you want.

Even if your problem is not caused mainly by this, this approach is better. You should either use [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) or [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) to work with network requests.

Comment: This seems like really helpful information.  We are learning as we go with this stuff.  I will get back to you regarding this.  Right now I can tell you plugging in the awaits is giving us some Webpack version errors.  It's saying we need 2.0 but im not sure if that's really the problem.  I will get back to you on this. Thanks for the info!!I  I'll update and accept if this is the solution,

Comment: So this fixed the issue.  We had to add an additional plug to get babel to transpile these awaits correctly.  We were getting async errors from webpack.  We are webpack 1.13 and babel 6.x generally.  This is the package we added.  It's a transform regenerator.  https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-regenerator

Comment: Thank you very much.  This really helped with this problem and just in general helped us get a better understanding of the async in React!!

Comment: @Puerto i am glad to help you!

Comment: one followup.  all those methods are using the isomorphic fetch library which is a promise based fetch, so I thought I was using promise for network requests already.  now it seems I'm using both await and promise??

Comment: @Puerto Yes you are using promises while making requests. It is fine. But the problem is the methods/functions that contain those requests. Those methods don't wait for the requests  until complete. That's why we need to specify those `async` / `await` expressions. To tell the javascript wait and do not execute next line.